# Возможно ли запросить права администратора уже запущенному приложению?

Tags: c#, wpf, uac

Сделал небольшой инсталлятор на WPF. По умолчанию запускается с обычными правами, но если пользователь выберет защищенную директорию для установки, нужны будут права. Можно ли попросить повышение прав уже запущенному приложению? Или сразу при запуске требовать права администратора и все? Но хотелось бы только в крайних случаях.

Comment: В манифесте приложения прописать привелегии.

Comment: Но я бы вам не рекомендовал использовпть элевацию прав, если она ситуативная и не требуется для полноценной работы приложения. Если юзер хочет в защищенную папку поставить, он в состоянии запустить инсталлер сам от админа.

Comment: спасибо, так и поступлю. А при выборе защищённой папки просто дам уведомление пользователю, что не хватает привилегий.

Comment: Главное сделайте так, чтобы инсталлер не падал, когда происходят ошибки записи файлов. Вот вам ссылка про манифест на всякий случай https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776/12888024